# What kind of magic or technology would be necessary to survive in a stone spaceship?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, medieval, survival

Imagine a typical fantasy setting: magic is fairly common, and technology is the usual combination of medieval Europe with a dash of steampunk.

The world goes through a cataclysm and the people are forced to become a spacefaring people. They start out with stone ships - essentially flying castles - and some stores of basic supplies like food, water, wood, ore. Luckily they also have a few pieces of deus ex machina magic: a way to create breathable air, a way to create artificial gravity, and a way to warp/teleport their ships over great distances.

What are some other pieces of technology or magic will they need to survive and eventually prosper? What are some of their unique challenges?

Comment: A slightly different take: The Doctor Who Serial *[Ghost Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Light_(Doctor_Who))* (1989) used a stone spaceship that travelled "*at the speed of thought*," even easily through solid matter. The crew needed only the will to explore; the ship provided the rest. It was originally inhabited by a powerful alien taxonomist. Unfortunately, his Survey got a bit out of Control....

Answer (score 4):

**You need heat, air, water, and food. That's about it.**

I'm going to just... ignore physics for the purpose of this answer because they have magic, so we don't have to worry about the rocket equation or fuel or any of that sort of business. I'm pretty sure there was a D&D expansion that had a lot of this sort of thing. I remember mind-flayer spacecraft anyway.

So.

Humans need a constant temperature, so you need heat sources. Humans need to breathe so you need a source of fresh air. Humans need to drink so you need a source of fresh water. Putting my D&D hat on, summing the appropriate elements from their various elemental planes of Fire, Water, and Air would easily serve for all these functions.

The fourth critical need is food. Again, we're using magic here so I'm sure a cleric can just summon manna, or if someone has one of those Horns of Endless Plenty or whatever. For the purposes of your story it really depends on how happy you want people to be with the food.

As far as prospering, this assumes people are going to make more people, which means your population is going to grow and eventually fill up your flying castle, which means that ultimately you're going to need ways to either build new castles, or expand the ones you have or both, and that means raw materials of stone, ore, wood, what-have-you.

Depending on what kind of story you're telling here, this may be solvable via trade with other travelers, but there has to be a source of fresh materials somewhere, or it's a zero-sum environment. Maybe there are asteroids you can mine with the appropriate magical space-suits or what-have-you. You can maybe even turn them into floating gardens and do a magical sort of hydroponic zero-g agriculture there.

If there are other planets they can visit, then there's a source of raw materials, but that raises the question of why they wouldn't just land their castles on a habitable planet and STAY there. Not much reason to leave unless they're forced to.

Anyway, there's lots of options.

Comment: The D&D spells you might be interested in are *goodberry*, *create or destroy water*, *create bonfire*, and (this is going to sound weird) *water breathing*. Most wind-themed spells just *affect* wind rather than create it, so if you want to breathe using minimal magic, you're better off ritual casting *water breathing* and dunking your head in a bucket. *Fabricate* would let you turn CO2 back into O2, but it's a 4th level spell and can't be ritual casted.

Comment: You won't want create bonfire as that would use more air. Heat metal would be better as no flame

Comment: A stone ship you could use a continuous light spell and grow some plants

Comment: Depending on where you are in space, you may be more in need of cooling than heating.

Answer (score 3):

**Navigation**

May the Gods have mercy on their souls if they want to spacefare without advanced navigation. Of course, you can just teleport magically to Mars or Venus, and eyeball your flying castle's motion to remain in orbit, even then it would need a lot of practice and accidents will happen (potentially deadly).
To go outside of the Solar System and don't end up stranded, then you need telescopes and an exaustive data base of stars. Again, lots of castles will get stranded.